# Error al enviar SMS desde cel. con saldo

Tags: java, android, sms

Bien, tengo una app que envía sms en segundo plano. Todo bien hasta aquí, probé la app desde mi cel (proveedor tigo) . y el sms se envio correctamente. Pero intente enviarlo desde otro cel (proveedor avantel). y al abrir la app de mensajería aparece un error "no se envió el mensaje, presione para volver a intentarlo". Efectivamente se presionaba y ahí si se enviaba.
¿Alguna solución?. tengo permisos en el manifestó y también los solicito al iniciar la app.

**Anexo todos mis permisos del manifesto.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SMS_FINANCIAL_TRANSACTIONS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

**codigo con el que envio los sms**

public void sms(String numero, String mensaje) {

```
SmsManager mySmsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
mySmsManager.sendTextMessage(numero, null, mensaje, null, null);
```

}

Comment: Podrías revisar la configuración APN en Avantel y verifica que esté todo correcto. [APN_Avantel_Android](https://www.avantel.co/files/apn-Android_20200626.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

El ùnico permiso que necesitas en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` es

Este permiso lo debes requerir manualmente:

```
private void checkSMSStatePermission() {
    int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
    if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "No se tiene permiso para enviar SMS.");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 225);
    } else {
        Log.i("Mensaje", "Se tiene permiso para enviar SMS!");
    }
}
```

Este serìa tu mètodo:

```
public void sms(String numero, String mensaje) {

  SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
  sms.sendTextMessage(numero, null, mensaje , null, null);
}
```